# Send values from content page to master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one login page and one master page with one label on it. So, what I want is when any user logs in, his Email ID should be sent from the login page to the master page and change the text of that label to that Email ID.

Comment: What have you tried? Public accesors? passing the value in a constructor? Public Field? Anything?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a Label on MasterPage and setting the text of Label in Content Page.

Code of Content Page, setting the Label control of Master Page.

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lbl As Label = TryCast(Me.Master.FindControl("lblMasterPage"), Label)
    lbl.Text = "Setting Label from Content Page"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now but only for the login page. When I redirect to another page the Email ID disappears..

Comment: You should store values in Session or QueryString to pass between web pages. Please refer following link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Public variables?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use `Session Variables`

```
Session["EmailID"] = <your_mailID_value>;
```

Now you can access that value everywhere in your application.

This is particularly useful in Account based applications where you can store all important variables like UserID, Name, Email into correspoding sessions and access them globally throughout your application. This reduces fetching of this values in every page or wherever these are needed.

Answer (score 0):

**In apsx.cs**

Label lblEmail = this.Master.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

lblEmail.Text = "Mail ID";

Include in aspx page   <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>